# Assigning a MouseListener to each Region in a 2d array of Regions

Tags: multidimensional-array, javafx, mouselistener

I posted a question here a couple weeks ago for some help on making a chess game and I got a great response and some code that demonstrates a solution to my problem. I have been trying to dissect the code and study it so I can better understand how it works. While doing this I ran into a question I can not seem to find an answer for. The chess board is made up of a 2d array of Regions and I am trying to add a MouseListener to each Region in the 2d array so that when a Region is pressed it will print out the row and column of the Region that was pressed. Right now nothing is happening when I press on a square in my screen and I can't not figure out why my MouseListener is not working.

```
 public class Main extends Application {
 GridPane root = new GridPane();
 final int size = 8;
 int col = 0;
 int row = 0; 

 @Override
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {


        GridPane board = new GridPane();
        Region[][] fields = new Region[8][8];
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            Region[] flds = fields[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < flds.length; j++) {
                Region field = new Region();
                flds[j] = field;
                field.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill((i + j) % 2 == 0 ? Color.WHITE : Color.LIGHTBLUE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));

            }
            board.addRow(i, flds);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            col = i;
            for (int j = 0; j < fields[i].length; j++) {
                row = j;
                fields[i][j].setOnMouseClicked(e->{
                    System.out.println("Col:" + col + ", Row" + row);
                });
            }
        }

         // use 1/8 of the size of the Grid for each field
        RowConstraints rowConstraints = new RowConstraints();
        rowConstraints.setPercentHeight(100d / 8);
        ColumnConstraints columnConstraints = new ColumnConstraints();
        columnConstraints.setPercentWidth(100d / 8);

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            board.getColumnConstraints().add(columnConstraints);
            board.getRowConstraints().add(rowConstraints);
        }

        Pane piecePane = new Pane();
        StackPane root = new StackPane(board, piecePane);

       // NumberBinding boardSize = Bindings.min(root.widthProperty(), root.heightProperty());
        NumberBinding boardSize = Bindings.min(root.widthProperty(), root.heightProperty());

        // board size should be as large as possible but at most the min of the parent sizes
        board.setPrefSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);

        // same size for piecePane
        piecePane.setPrefSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        piecePane.maxWidthProperty().bind(boardSize);
        piecePane.maxHeightProperty().bind(boardSize);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
StackPane root = new StackPane(board,piecePane);
```

to:

```
StackPane root = new StackPane(piecePane,board);
```

?
Because the `board` was behind the `piecePane` it couldn't receive events.

Before you were using **global variables** `col` and `row` so these variables had always the same value of `7` and `7`. Running the loop those variables where changing their value,but at the end they had the values `7` `7` , here we need to use **local variables** `col` and `row` , so you need to add this modification:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                int col = i;
                for (int j = 0; j < fields[i].length; j++) {
                    int row = j;
                    fields[i][j].setOnMouseClicked(e -> System.out.println("Col:" + col + ", Row" + row));
                }
            }
```

Comment: Cool that makes my MouseListener work, thank you! I am assigning the MouseListener is the correct spot? because no matter where I click on the screen it displays row 7 col 7.

Comment: @Nick Ops let me check that

Comment: Cool thank you. In most of my projects I use a Group and usually only one so I am still trying to wrap my head around this code.

Comment: @Nick Ready! Edited...Be careful with `Group` cause it has some limitations.... like it not resizing..

Comment: Isn't that the same as what I had? Yours seem to just be one line. It seems like both for loops are completely running and the the MouseListener executes.

Comment: @Nick Nope.Before you were using global variables `col` and `row` so these variables had always the same value of `7` and `7`. Running the loop those variables where changing their value,but at the end they had the values `7` `7` , here i am using local variables `col` and `row`.Small difference but it is knowledge of core Java.

Comment: Oh I get it now. Wow that's awesome, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127853/discussion-between-nick-and-goxr3plus).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked much in JavaFX myself, though it is very similar to java swing regarding basic "collision".

There is a [rectangle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Rectangle.html) class with the methods `contains` and `intersects`. If you use [MouseEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html) to know the mouse coordinates and when the mouse is clicked. You can do something like this:

```
if(mouse.isClicked() && rect.contains(mouse.x, mouse.y) { // do stuff }
```

You need to create rectangle objects for all the squares though. Hope it works out.

**EDIT:** Noticed [Regions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html) also contained the methods `contains` and `intersects` - try these beforehand, use rectangles only if you must to skip too much object creation.

Comment: Yea I just looked them up to and saw those methods. Thank you for the advice, I am going to read and play around with those methods and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Couldn't get that to work either. I tried setting a MouseListener to the piecePane but it is not working.